# How to configure bot framework C# slack adapter to work with multiple workspaces?

Tags: botframework

I have a bot in C# working with botbuilder-dotnet using the slack-adapter with my workspace. Now I want to install the slack app in other workspaces.
How can I configure the adapter to work with multiple workspaces? I think it's around this options in the constructor but couldn't find any examples: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/497cb6e5192c85a82478aca475f324dd3afde4cf/libraries/Adapters/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Adapters.Slack/SlackClientWrapper.cs#L214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the Bot Framework does not support multiple workspaces as of 4/22/21.

---

You did the right thing by creating a feature request in the GitHub repo. For others who're searching for this issue and would like for it to gain traction, see link tracking the issue:

https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/5519

The Bot Framework team will look into and assign priority to, should they decide to implement the feature request